# How can i set this redirect only for anonymous users?

Tags: 8

```
namespace Drupal\project_extras\EventSubscriber;

use Drupal\Core\Url;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;

class RedirectAnonymousSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface {


  public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
    // This announces which events you want to subscribe to.
    // We only need the request event for this example.  Pass
    // this an array of method names
    return([
      KernelEvents::REQUEST => [
        ['redirectMyContentTypeNode'],
      ]
    ]);
  }


  /**
   * Redirect requests for my_content_type node detail pages to node/123.
   *
   * @param GetResponseEvent $event
   * @return void
   */

  public function redirectMyContentTypeNode(GetResponseEvent $event) {

    $request = $event->getRequest();

    // This is necessary because this also gets called on
    // node sub-tabs such as "edit", "revisions", etc.  This
    // prevents those pages from redirected.
    if ($request->attributes->get('_route') !== 'entity.node.canonical') {
      return;
    }

    // Only redirect a certain content type.
    if ($request->attributes->get('node')->getType() !== 'specific_content_type') {
      return;
    }

    // This is where you set the destination.
    $redirect_url = Url::fromUri('entity:node/10');
    $response = new RedirectResponse($redirect_url->toString(), 301);
    $event->setResponse($response);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can load a user and check for authentication

```
$currentUser = \Drupal::currentUser();

// Do nothing if the user is authenticated.
if ($currentUser->isAuthenticated()) {
  return;
}
```

Comment: How can i add multiple content types? How can i create array?

Comment: You can refer to this article http://enzolutions.com/articles/2015/12/03/how-to-get-a-list-of-content-types-in-drupal-8/ for getting list of all content type

Comment: I don't want all content types. I'm tryin to create array so i can specify content type.
This is how i will do just for one content type
if ($request->attributes->get('node')->getType() !== 'one_content_type') {
      return;
    }

Comment: You can try this code

$current_content_type = $request->attributes->get('node')->getType();

$contentTypes = \Drupal::service('entity.manager')->getStorage('node_type')->loadMultiple();

$contentTypesList = [];
foreach ($contentTypes as $contentType) {
  $contentTypesList[$contentType->id()] = $contentType->label();
}

if (in_array($current_content_type, $contentTypesList)) {
  return;
}